# Angularjs $http put request to REST api using mongoose mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Could someone share an alternative update api with me? I have a model named "performers" which has a “score” property. I want to increment the score with a request from an Angularjs controller to the Mongo DB.  I can't quite find a way to do the incrementing.

I've looked a ton of places .. here is the mongoose documentation

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

this another giving some clues about argument syntax

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

and mongo speaking directly to the $inc
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc

heres is the request  I am trying (from client side angular controller) with
example data passed ( the keys are mongodb ids)

```
  performerScoreDeltas = { 343l88jkjkjkuuiui: -20, iii88909jkmmmkjjkj: 13,  iooiuo8889ee888: -9, popopbi99r8765: 7, 898989kv908098: 5, 798v8978fw79798: 25, a90va089898as9: 9 } 

 //from my angularjs controller for the page
 $scope.updateDbScores = function(performerScoreDeltas){
    for(var eventScore in performerScoreDeltas){
      $http.put('/api/performers/' + eventScore, {$inc:{score: performerScoreDeltas[eventScore]}})
    }
  } 

   // from my api for the performer model
   exports.update = function(req, res) {
     if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
     Performer.findById(req.params.id, function (err, performer) {
       if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
       if(!performer) { return res.status(404).send('Not Found'); }
       var updated = _.merge(performer, req.body);
       updated.save(function (err) {
         if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
           return res.status(200).json(performer);
         });
      });
    };
```

I've been getting 200 responses for the updates, yet the score property isn't changed. The requests get to the right place though and looking at my chrome dev tools I see the request is carrying a "payload" of {$inc:{score:-20}} for an id I want to decrease the score by by 20 etc.

Question: Do I need to make a special API route and somehow hardwire more of the $inc into it and only have the request pass data?

Here is the angularjs $http documentation 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put

I'm stuck. The needed information seems to be getting there but maybe it is because my api controller is using the save method instead of the update method?

Could someone share with me an alternative RESTFUL api code that uses update instead?  I'll admit that the block I use comes from a yeoman package.  It does work well for normal updates I have implemented and even worked editing the _.merge  (hmm... maybe I could change the merge to include the $inc? ...but it would need data from the params)